# How to include/use JQuery in Magento2 Blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, php, magento2

I am trying to use JQuery in my block functions, but I get an error saying JQuery not found. I tried google and some suggested to add it to local.xml but I think Magento2 does not have local.xml.

Can anyone help me on how to enable JQuery in Magento2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use requirejs to manage/resolve dependencies in JS code. For example

```
require(
  ['jquery'], // list of dependencies
  function($) {
     //put your code that use jquery here
  } 
)
```

See [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/why.html) for more detais